# class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeku not found

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

I want to implement firebase into my application and i had this problem.

I do not have any idea on how to solve this issue.

> error: cannot access zzeku class file for
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeku not found

Here is my build.gradle::

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()

        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            maven{
                url 'https://maven.google.com'
            }

        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

and here is my app build.gradle::

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 29
        buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.yanitow"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 29
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:1.0.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:1.0.2'
        implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
        implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

i hope someone has a solution for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to different version of firebase.PLease make sure to update and use all Library with same Version.